# Get generated element from directive in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the wrapper: https://github.com/Yankovsky/nouislider-angular/blob/master/nouislider.js

for nouislider plugin. And in my controller I want to get element, that I created in template:

```
<div ya-no-ui-slider='options'></div>
```

to call method from original plugin: `slider.querySelector('.noUi-pips');`

I found this:

```
// allow to get noUiSlider instance from outside of that directive
that.getNoUiSlider = function() {
    return noUiSliderInstance;
};
```

in source: https://github.com/Yankovsky/nouislider-angular/blob/master/nouislider.js#L58

How could I call it to get an instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the scope from outside the directive, which is something like:

```
var scopeFromSlider =  $(".selector").scope();
```

Can be also

```
angular.element(".details-container").scope()
```

Comment: yes, thank you, you are right. But i can't find this method in object that `scope()` returns for me.

Comment: it returns me `ChildScope` object